# Find out UI element is owned by which addon

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In WOW, is there a way I can find out a specific UI element, say an extra line in the tooltip, or a floating frame, is provided by which addon (or default UI)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/framestack` command will give you information regarding each user interface element including details of which addon it is related to.

[image]

Simply type `/framestack` into the chat window, and then hover over the user interface element you want details on. In the above screenshot I am hovering over the VuhDo healing interface, which shows `<2> Vd4` (and all of the elements on top of that element).